# What novel by John Brunner features a rock band called "Girdano Bruno and the Hermetic Tradition"?

Tags: story-identification, novel

I'm looking for a novel by John Brunner featuring a rock band named "Giordano Bruno and the Hermetic Tradition."  There is a book called "Giordano Bruno and the Hermetic Tradition" which probably inspired the title's use.

Comment: Is there some sci-fi or fantasy element to this book?

Comment: A quick Google search also reveals a book titled "Frances Yates and the Hermetic Tradition", so it's probably just about [Hermeticism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermeticism), rather than inspired by whatever the answer to this question is.

Answer (score 5):

It's [*Double, Double*](http://books.google.com/books/about/Double_Double.html?id=Umiszdry47MC).

You remembered a little too much -- the band is RidgebackBruno and Hermetic Tradition.